# Where like query builder in Laravel with MongoDb

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I'm trying to make a where ... like in Laravel with MongoDb for my search bar. In mysql I created with:

```
DB::table('Account')->where('avail_balance','like','%' .$searchValue . '%');
```

But with MongoDb Jenssegers, I can't use it. It's return nothing. 
After search some post in here, I use:

```
$account = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('Account')->where('avail_balance',"%{$searchValue}%")->paginate(5);
```

It's still return nothing. 
How I should convert this query from mysql to mongodb?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this with the end of **`get()`** method:

```
DB::table('Account')->where('avail_balance','LIKE','%'.$searchValue.'%')->get();
```

And try this using **`LIKE`** query:

```
$account = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('Account')->where('avail_balance','LIKE','%'.$searchValue.'%')->paginate(5);
```

I hope it would helpful.